# WinHTTP IWinHttpRequest iface - cookie handling - how to get cookies from response?

Tags: c++, http, com, post, winhttp

I'm using WinHTTP IWinHttpRequest object. I do POST to a https domain specyfying a request body with credentials. The site is expected to return cookies in HTTP response. The code works in Wininet - but I don't know how in WinHTTP to get cookies from the HTTP response?

Can anybody help?

Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the [Cookie Handling in WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383261(VS.85).aspx) article on MSDN.

If you want to do things manually, here's an (ugly) VB code sample you can crib from: http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.exchange.development/topic58495.aspx)